# How to mock a worker for a Jest test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, web-worker

I have a test:

```
import { convertHeicToPng } from './heicUtils';

class Worker {
  url: string;
  onmessage: (m?: any) => void;
  constructor(stringUrl: string) {
    this.url = stringUrl;
    this.onmessage = () => {};
  }

  postMessage(msg: any) {
    this.onmessage(msg);
  }
}

(window.Worker as any) = Worker;

describe('test heicUtils', () => {
  test('should convert HEIC to PNG', async () => {
    const file = new File([''], 'test.heic', { type: 'image/heic' });
    const base64 = await convertHeicToPng(file);
    expect(base64).toContain('data:image/png;base64');
  });
});
```

and in `heicUtils`, I'm using [heic2any](https://github.com/alexcorvi/heic2any), which uses WebWorkers. How can I properly mock a Worker for a Jest test?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with your implementation? Are you missing several features of a Worker and don't want to manually implement them or are you running into errors that you wouldn't expect with your mock?

Comment: The library's author should test it works fine. You may want to test that you do pass the correct arguments there, and that when your receive a result you do handle it correctly, but you probably don't have to test what happens in between. If you really need to test that e.g you do transfer data correctly etc. you may want to use a `MessageChannel` to use the same [StructureSerializeWithTransfer](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/structured-data.html#structuredserializewithtransfer) algorithm than Workers, but even then that'd be testing node's implementation and not your code per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are testing your `heicUtils` module, you should mock the `heic2any` lib, otherwise, you will be testing the 3rd party library instead of your own code.

In the mock, you should define the functions/methods of `heic2any` that your `heicUtils` use and what they should return for each test case you intend to write.

Examples of how to mock modules can be found here: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

Answer (score 2):

if you are using typescript, adding this code to your jest setup file might work:

```
type MessageHandler = (msg: string) => void;

class Worker {
    url: string;
    onmessage: MessageHandler;
    constructor(stringUrl: string) {
        this.url = stringUrl;
        this.onmessage = noop;
    }
    postMessage(msg: string): void {
        this.onmessage(msg);
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'Worker', {
    writable: true,
    value: Worker
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tsc   && mocha     --reporter spec  -t 5000  --exit

.npm install mocha
.then do this cmd
.Examples my github : https://github.com/www778878net/koa78-base78

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck